# Rust generics: expected type parameter, found &T

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm new to rust, just dabbling.
I'm trying to implement a generic queue, no production reason, just getting familiar with the language.

I have:

```
pub struct Queue<T> {
    container: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Queue<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Queue {
            container: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn enqueue(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.container.push(item);
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.container.is_empty() {
            return None;
        } else {
            let result = self.container.first();
            self.container.remove(0);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
5  | impl<T> Queue<T> {
   |      - this type parameter
...
16 |     pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
   |                               --------- expected `std::option::Option<T>` because of return type
...
22 |             return result;
   |                    ^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `&T`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<T>`
              found enum `std::option::Option<&T>`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

As far as I understand, the problem here is that what `first()` returns is a reference to a value in the containing vector, instead of getting a copy of said value. However, I don't quite know how I can take an arbitrary item from the vector, and return it from the `next()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust collections typically give you back ownership of elements you remove from them. This is the case of [`Vec::remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove):

> ### `pub fn remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> T`
>
> Removes *and returns* the element at position index within the vector, shifting all elements after it to the left.

(emphasis is mine)

This means you can do the following:

```
pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    if self.container.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(self.container.remove(0))
    }
}
```

You should also consider using [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) which seems better suited for your case and has a [`pop_front`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.pop_front) which does exactly what you are doing.

Comment: looks like I over-complicated it a bit, thanks for the help!